# Creating Objectiv-C object with custom init in Swift results in Optional - Why?

Tags: ios, swift

**TL;DR:** Why is an Objectiv-C object created as Swift Optional when assigned to a var before returning it as func result and as Non-Optional when returning it directly?

**Details:**

I would like to use some existing Objectiv-C code in Swift. A Swift methods creates and returns an `UIViewController`. This does not work as expected when working with a `UIViewController` class implemented in  Objectiv-C

```
// SomeViewController.h
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController { }
- (id)initWithData:(MyData *)data;
@end

// SomeViewController.m
@implementation SomeViewController { }

- (id)initWithData:(MyData *)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}

@end


// Swift
func foo() -> UIViewController {
    return SomeViewController(data: someData)   // Works fine

}

func foo() -> UIViewController {
    // ERROR: Value of optional type 'SomeViewController?' must be 
    // unwrapped to a value of type 'SomeViewController'
    let vs = SomeViewController(data: someData)  
    return vc

    ---
    // No problem when using standard init
    let vs = SomeViewController()   
    return vc                                   // Works fine
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the initialization method provided by the CocoaTouch frameworks can never be return nil value。However, custom initializers method can return nil value。
for example

// SomeViewController.h

```objectivec
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController { }
- (id)initWithData:(MyData *)data;
@end

// SomeViewController.m
@implementation SomeViewController { }

- (id)initWithData:(MyData *)data {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

or overwrite init method

```objectivec
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController { }
- (id)init;
@end

// SomeViewController.m
@implementation SomeViewController { }

- (id)init {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

---

Xcode BUG

```swift
func foo() -> UIViewController {
    // returns nil will be crash!!!
    // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    return SomeViewController(data: someData)   // unsafe
}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL160.png)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C initializers can return `nil` unless you specify otherwise in the initializer's declaration, so Swift has no choice but to infer its type to be `Optional`.

The easiest way to specify non-nullability is to bracket your `.h` file with nullability assumptions:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController

// This initializer is specified to not return `nil`. It is up to you to ensure that this is the case in your implementation. 
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData*)data;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The reason that the built-in initializers don't infer type as optional is because they have all been audited and explicitly declared to be either nullable on non-nullable.

More details: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25